# Fastest way to clone a github repo to computer without having to delete older versions, just update the changed files?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I'm using Github desktop but whenever I try to sync to get the updated files it tells me syncing would overwrite my uncommited changes (probably the config file) and either to commit or discard them. So I have to delete the whole thing and then put in all my settings back into the config file which wasn't even updated.
Is there a better program to do this?

Comment: [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) is the best GUI client I know but I keep using git from the shell, if you want find out more clients sorted by popularity here: http://alternativeto.net/software/sourcetree/

Comment: You could always try to do what it says. Stash your changes and then pull down is the easiest way to achieve this. I don't use GitHub desktop but any good client should allow you to do this ( I use gitkraken ). Also if you want to edit the config file locally, but never commit those changes, I'd suggest adding it to gitignore file. This will resolve your problem too

Comment: @gentlesea How would I do something like this but with source tree?

http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/pokemon-go/pokemon-go-hacks-cheats/563371-how-update-your-bots-keep-your-changes-locally.html